# Want to be able to drag the things in the listbox into the workspace

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to get the content in the listbox able to be dragged into the workspace as a block. Like scratch. I used OpenAi to give me ideas of how to do it, and it gave me that there is a draggable option I can put into the code as you can see, but when I try to drag the items in the listbox it wont let me.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import ImageGrab

# Create a list of Python code to display in the scroller
code_lines = [
    "variable",
    "loops",
    "types of variables"
]

# Create the window layout
layout = [  [sg.Column([[sg.Listbox(values=code_lines, size=(20, 10), key='Python Code', draggable = True)]]),
             sg.Column([[sg.Text('Workspace:', size=(20, 1)), sg.Multiline(size=(50, 30), key='workspace', background_color='dark gray')]])],
            [sg.Button('Close')] ]

# Create the window
window = sg.Window('PyDrop', layout)

# Event loop to process events
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Close':  # if user closes window or clicks close button
        break
    elif event == 'Python Code':  # if user clicks on an item in the listbox
        # stores the value of the clicked item in a variable
        dragged_item = values['Python Code'][0]
    elif event == sg.DRAG:  # if user moves the mouse while holding down the button
        # updates the value of the drop target
        print('Drag event triggered')
        window['drop_target'].update(dragged_item)


# Close the window
window.close()
```

Comment: The answer should be No, not only without the `dragable` option and not dragable, also no event generated if you don't specify `enable_events=True`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.